# Почему после fs.writeFileSync аудио является некорректным?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, файловая-система, pipes

Я использую `prequest`. Мне нужно было скачать трек:

```
let track = await prequest(url);
fs.writeFileSync('track.mp3', track);
```

Но после скачивания получившийся файл не воспроизводится, а весит больше, чем на деле должно быть.

Другой метод работает, но уже с библиотекой `request`:

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('track.mp3'));
```

Корректно воспроизводится файл и размер точный. В чём ошибка при использовании `prequest` и простой записи полученного с сайта бинарника в файл? Чем `pipe` отличается?

Comment: В содержимое полученного файла заглядывали?

Comment: @andreymal Разные, разумеется

Comment: Ну а какое конкретно-то? Если первый файл весит больше, значит в нём какие-то лишние байты добавились, смотрели какие? Даже открытие банальным Блокнотом (и плевать что это аудиофайл) может дать подсказку

Comment: Ну а вообще prequest возвращает текстовую строку, в то время как аудиофайл очевидно не является текстовой строкой — это наверняка портит файл и возможно и является причиной проблемы

Comment: @andreymal да, при выводе в консоль он так и выводился, строкой. И как же из этого получить 
 корректный Buffer?